# Processes randomly freezing, get stuck reading /proc/pid/environ

Tags: linux, process, manjaro, proc

So my computer is behaving weirdly in many ways which might or might not be related to hardware problems. This question is about a reproducible symptom of that, which I'm trying to investigate.

When I run some computationally intensive job, e.g. try to compile a large software project using gcc or do cpu training using PyTorch, a process will occasionally get stuck. When that happens:

1. The process freezes
2. Sending it kill signals does nothing
3. `top` shows its state as `D`, uninterruptable_sleep:

```
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                         
   3513 ---      20   0   59788  20992  15360 D   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 cc1plus
```

4. tools like `htop`, `ps` or the KDE System Monitor fail to start and instead freeze
5. Running `strace ps` shows

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/3513/environ", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4,
```

as the syscall at which it's stuck at

6. And indeed, doing `cat /proc/3513/environ` freezes up the terminal.

The only way I have found to restore normality is to restart my pc.

Any further debugging leads would be appreciated. Thanks!

**System info**

Software: Manjaro Linux, Kernel 6.4.6, but reproducible on other distros/kernels/gcc versions.

Hardware:

```
Processors: 32 × 13th Gen Intel® Core™ i9-13900K
Memory: 62.6 GiB of RAM
Motherboard: MPG Z790 EDGE WIFI (MS-7D91)
```

To check for hardware issues I ran memcheck86+, IPDT and stress-ng, none of them found any problems.